# Finding Maximum in Key Value RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a key-value RDD of the form :

```scala
(Some(23661587),
CompactBuffer(Posting(2,23661643,Some(23661587),0,None), 
              Posting(2,23661682,Some(23661587),0,None)))
```

Here `Some(23661587)` is the key and data inside `CompactBuffer` is the value. I want to select the `Posting` type with maximum value for a particular attribute for each key.

How can I do that? I have limited experience in Scala and Spark.
Thanks

Comment: `CompactBuffer` extends `Seq`. Please look at the `Seq` [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Seq.html) to see what functions are available to you. It shouldn't be too hard to figure out the correct approach from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your example with some data.

As @sinanspd said, `org.apache.spark.util.collection.CompactBuffer` extends from `scala.collection.immutable.Seq`,
you can follow this link [CompactBuffer](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/collection/CompactBuffer.scala),
so you can use methods from `scala.collection.immutable.Seq` [Seq](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.12/scala/collection/immutable/Seq.html) to sort the Seq and get the `Posting` max value.

My choice was `Posting.value` to sort the Seq but it could be value2 or any field in Posting class.

As an example

```scala
object FindingMaximum {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("FindingMaximum")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  case class Posting(key: Int, value: Long, value2: Option[Long], value3: Int, value4: Option[Int])

  val data = List((Some(23661587),Seq(Posting(2,23661643,Some(23661587),0,None), Posting(2,23661682,Some(23661587),0,None))),
                  (Some(23661588),Seq(Posting(3,23661743,Some(23661588),0,None), Posting(3,23661682,Some(23661588),0,None))),
                  (Some(23661589),Seq(Posting(4,23661843,Some(23661589),0,None), Posting(4,23661882,Some(23661589),0,None))))

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)

    val rddKeyMax = rdd.map({case(key, v) =>
      val max = v.sortBy(posting => posting.value).last
      (key, max)
    })
    rddKeyMax.foreach(println)
  }
}

/*
(Some(23661588),Posting(3,23661743,Some(23661588),0,None))
(Some(23661587),Posting(2,23661682,Some(23661587),0,None))
(Some(23661589),Posting(4,23661882,Some(23661589),0,None))
*/
```